# Prime sieve algorithm

Tags: python-2.7, prime-factoring

```
quuNumm = int(input("ENTER NUMBER : "))
```

for quuP in range(2, int(quuNumm ** 0.5)) :

```
if (quuNumm % quuP == 0) : 

    print("{} is NOT PRIME " . format(quuNumm)) 


elif (quuNumm % quuP != 0) : 

    print("{} is prime ".format(quuNUmm)) 

    break 

else : 

    print("ENTER NONNEGATIVE NUMBER PLEASE")
```

I keep getting this error : ENTER NUMBER : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 12, in 
NameError: name 'quuNUmm' is not defined

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo—an incorrect upper-case "U". It should be `quuNumm`, not `quuNUmm` in the call to `format()`.

EDIT: The logic you should be following (here in pseudocode) is:

1. [input] obtain user input `n` until `n` is valid
2. [initialize] declare a composite flag and set it to `false`
3. [loop] for each number `x` in the range `2..sqrt(n)` (inclusive):
   if `x` evenly divides `n`, set the composite flag to `true` and break out of the loop
4. [output] if the composite flag is `true`, report that `n` is not prime; otherwise report that it is prime

Comment: Thank you @Ted Hopp. Is it possible to explain the mathematical logic behind the prime sieve please?

Comment: @iivri andre - Sure, but please realize that the code you posted is **not** a sieve algorithm. For info on a prime number sieve, check out [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). Your code is a brute-force test. The mathematical logic is that if a number is not prime, it is divisible by an integer that is no larger than the square root of the number. (It doesn't matter if the square root is an integer; the point is that if it is divisible by a number larger than the square root, the quotient will be another divisor smaller than the square root.)

Comment: Ok. when i ran the algorithm with 16 it return "16 is prime and 16 is not prime at the same time ? " How can I fix this?

Comment: @ Ted Hopp I placed a break statement after the ` if (quuNumm % quuP == 0) : 
        
        print("{} is NOT PRIME " . format(quuNumm))` it work but I am not sure why.

Comment: @iivri andre - The number is prime only if it is not divisible by _all_ numbers no greater than the square root. You are printing "not prime" if it is not divisible by _any_ number. So, for instance, 16 is not divisible by 3, but that doesn't mean that it's prime. The best thing to do is to set a flag as soon as you detect that the number is not prime and then exit the loop. After the loop exits, print that the number is prime only if the flag is not set (that is, if it was not divisible by any number tested).

Comment: @ Ted Hopp Where would the flag go? I am having problems create the required design pattern for the program with the various sections positioned correctly.

Comment: @iivri andre - Define the flag before the loop starts and initialize it to `false`. If you detect that the number is not prime, set the flag to `true` and break out of the loop. Then after the loop exits (either because of a `break` or because all the possible divisors have been tested), print that it is prime only if the flag is still `false`.

Comment: Ok. @Ted Hopp. Thank you again for your assistance, I really appreciate it. Is it possible the you could represent the **The number is prime only if it is not divisible by all numbers no greater than the square root. You are printing "not prime" if it is not divisible by any number** statement using the symbols in logic. I want to understand the representational logic behind it so I can improve how I illustrate the code. Would existential and universal symbols be relevant?

Comment: @iivri andre - I'm not sure how representational logic would help more than simply documenting the code. If desired, one could define the predicate C(n) to mean "the number n is composite (not prime)". Then C(n) is logically equivalent to "there existing a number x greater than 1 and no greater than the square root of n, such that n is evenly divisible by x". The predicate P(n) (meaning "n is prime") would be the negation of C(n): "for all numbers x greater than one and no greater than the square root of n, n is not evenly divisible by x." I hope that makes clear what quantifier to use where.

Comment: lol @Ted Hopp You are right, it only complicates things for me. I just wanted to merge both mathematics and programming in my practice so I can be a better programmer. I am interested in machine learning so I think I need to be mathematically inclined. Incidentally I placed `quuNumm = False`before the if statement in the for loop and it gave me this **ENTER NUMBER : False is NOT PRIME** so I guess I am wrong. Please bare with me I am COMPLETELY new to the world of programming.

Comment: @iivri andre - You need to create a new variable for the flag. The variable `quuNumm` is supposed to hold the number being tested for primality. Also, initialize the flag to `False` immediately after receiving the input, before the `for` loop, not before the `if` statement inside the loop.

Comment: `quuNumm = int(input("ENTER NUMBER : "))
**quuNM = False**
for quuP in range(2, int(quuNumm ** 0.5)) : 
    if (quuNumm % quuP == 0) : 
        print("{} is NOT PRIME " . format(quuNumm)) 
        break
    elif (quuNumm % quuP != 0) : 
        print("{} is prime ".format(quuNumm))
    else : 
        print("ENTER NONNEGATIVE NUMBER PLEASE")` This is what I did and enter **407** as the number and this happened : **ENTER NUMBER : 407 is prime 
407 is prime 
407 is prime 
407 is prime 
407 is prime 
407 is prime 
407 is prime 
407 is prime 
407 is prime 
407 is NOT PRIME**

Comment: @iivri andre - Get rid of the `elif` part inside the loop. Instead, set `quuNM` to `True` just before the `break` statement. Then after the entire loop, add `if (!quuNM) : print ("{} is prime ".format(quuNumm))`. Also, test for non-negative number immediately after receiving the number, not every time through the loop.

Comment: `quuNumm = int(input("ENTER NUMBER : "))`
`quuNM = False`
for quuP in range(2, int(quuNumm ** 0.5)) : 
    `if quuNumm < 0 :` 
        `print("ENTER NONNEGATIVE NUMBER PLEASE")`
   `if (quuNumm % quuP == 0) :` 
        `print("{} is NOT PRIME " . format(quuNumm))` 
        `quuNM = True`
        `break`     
`if (quuNM) : print ("{} is prime ".format(quuNumm))`  @Ted Hopp This is what I did and I keep getting **quuNumm is not prime and quuNumm is prime** I honestly am getting frustrated with this. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @iivri andre - You almost have it. At the end, you should print that the number is prime if `quuNM` is **`false`**; you are printing that it's prime if `quuNM` is true. Also, you should move the test for `quuNumm < 0` to before the `for` loop. I've updated my answer with an outline of the logic I'm suggesting you use.

Comment: @ Ted Hopp Yes!!!!!!!!! I got it. Thank you **VERY** much. THis is the construct I have for the code : `quuNumm = int(input("ENTER NUMBER : "))` quuNM = False 
`if quuNumm < 0 : 
        print("ENTER NONNEGATIVE NUMBER PLEASE")` 
for quuP in range(2, int(quuNumm ** 0.5)) : if (quuNumm % quuP == 0) : print("{} is NOT PRIME " . format(quuNumm)) 
     quuNM = True 
     break
else : print("{} is Prime ". format(quuNumm)). Is it right? If not then I AM going the SCREAM! lol. Thank you again. I really have a lot of other small projects to do so I would LOVE to "collaborate" with you on them.